# Haskell Error: Not in scope: `GLFW.windowIsOpen'

Tags: opengl, haskell, glfw

I can find this in [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/GLFW-b/latest/doc/html/Graphics-UI-GLFW.html#v%3awindowIsOpen).

However, whenever I compile, I get the scope error.

Here is my code:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL as GL
import Graphics.UI.GLFW as GLFW
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL (($=))
import System.Environment (getArgs, getProgName)

import Control.Monad

main = do
  GLFW.initialize
  GLFW.openWindow (GL.Size 400 400) [GLFW.DisplayAlphaBits 8] GLFW.Window
  GLFW.windowTitle $= "openGL Test"

  render <- initialize'
  loop render

  GLFW.closeWindow
  GLFW.terminate


loop render = do
  render
  p <- GLFW.getKey GLFW.ESC
  unless (p == GLFW.Press) $ do
    isOpen <- GLFW.windowIsOpen
    when isOpen $ loop render

initialize' = do
  return $ do
    GL.clear [GL.ColorBuffer]
```

Comment: As mentioned below, the problem is that you are mixing up the packages `GLFW` and `GLFW-b`. You should use only one of the packages; not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the documentation you refer to is pretty old. There is a [new documentation for the latest version](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/GLFW/0.5.0.1/doc/html/Graphics-UI-GLFW.html).

`windowIsOpen` does not exist any longer, it seems to have been replaced by `getParam Opened`.

Comment: It's a different package (GLFW vs. GLFW-b). But they both have the same module. Guess the OP looked at the docs for the wrong package.

Comment: So, it seems that your code mixes the two packages, as, for instance `windowTitle` is not part of GLFW-b (but in GLFW), but `windowsIsOpen`is not part of GLFW (but in GLFW-b).